How to Extract the First Sentence with Highlighted Term and Surrounding Sentences in Solr
I'm working with Solr and need to extract the first sentence that matches the query along with its highlighted snippet and surrounding sentences. How can I achieve this using Solr?
Lets take this whole highlighted input:
Some sentence. First sentence before highlighting. Sentence with <em>HighlightedTerm</em>. Sentence after the highlighting. Some sentence. Another Sentence with <em>HighlightedTerm</em>

Expected output:
First sentence before highlighting. Sentence with <em>HighlightedTerm</em>. Sentence after the highlighting.

The only idea I had was to get the whole text with highlits from solr and tokenize the text by sentences and choose what I need. But I am wondering if solr API supports this what I need to some extent.
